# aws autoscaling group, scale down condition

Tags: amazon-web-services

As you can see in the screenshot

There's a cloudwatch alarm configuration (which sets numerical value of a metric)

And there's another configuration of the same metric to take `action`

Why do we need two? and what's the difference between the two?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you're displaying shows a [step scaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-step-scaling-policies.html).

In this scaling policy the CloudWatch alarm is the trigger that this scaling action should occur, when it "Alarms" the EC2 autoscaling service will then be triggered. A step scaling policy supports multiple actions for the same scaling action.

These actions (otherwise known at steps) allow you increase the amount of your scale-in / scale-out based on the severity of the alarm.

An example is you may have a scaling rule to scale out if average CPU is more than 60%. The actions might be:

- When between 60% and 70% scale up by 1
- When between 70% and 80% scale up by 2
- when between 80% and infinity scale up by 3